# Make specific url response 404 error instead of 200 for spam bots

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, spam, bots

How to make my site's specific url (index.php?act=add) to response 404 error instead of 200 when spam bots try to access it ?
I am not php programmer so may be it could be done somehow with derectives in .htaccess file ?

++++

Thank you for your answers but that did not help (
I need somthing like that rule in .htaccess file:

```
 <Files "index.php">
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 </Files>
```

But instead of index.php  to use "index.php?act=add".

+++
Now its working. Thank you!!!

Comment: You have to test for the [`evil bit`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3514). `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-I-Am-Evil} =1; RewriteRule - /404`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using php (file index.php)

```
if ($_GET['act'] == 'add') {
    if (condition to check spambot/useragent/ipaddress/cookie) {

        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        exit;

    } else {

        //
        //
        // your code for 'REAL' users

    }
}
```

Comment: And if `$_GET['act']` is not set, the code breaks horribly (depending on your error settings).

Comment: My answer is not a solution to the OP project. It is just a demo where the code should be placed. My code might not even go in index.php depending on his source!

Comment: this string helped :  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
Thank you for fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

you can use php headers

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

or use htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can use [header() function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), for example

```
if ($_GET["act"] == "add"){    
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```